# How can I apply a function to the third dimension of a array in R?

Tags: arrays, r

I have a array that organizes information by date as rows, different categories as columns, and different organizations collecting the data as the 3rd dimension.

How could I put such an array through an apply function, in the third array in order to return a data.frame of just the averaged columns and rows for all sources?
The data structure is a bit too difficult to write out, but here is the link for the GData I created.

```
load(url("http://www.clutchmemes.com/Random/GOPArray.RData"))
```

and the array is stored as `allGOP`. My thoughts were to do something like

```
apply(allGOP, 3, mean)
```

since 3 is the third dimension, yet it is returning a class of numeric.
I have also tried using the apply function in the `plyr` package, and it gives me the same thing.

Comment: The `(..., 3, ...)` is the dimension which rests. `> str(apply(allGOP, 3, mean))` 
 `Named num [1:26] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...` 
`- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:26] "Ipsos/Reuters" "Quinnipiac" "Gravis Marketing/One America News" "YouGov/Economist" ...` What is the desired result?

Comment: `data.frame(apply(allGOP, 3, mean, na.rm=T))`?